# Looking for some feeback on JSON music track list

Tags: json, database

Having some issues. I'm new to programming and am trying to find the best way to create a JSON track list for several DJ mixes I've done. Here's what I have... wondering if this is the right way to approach

```
{
"Title": "Notes For The HiFi",
"Volume": "One",
"MixDate": "September, 2015",
"Duration": "59:09",
"TrackCount": 19,
"Mix Type": "Blend Mix",
"Tracklist": {
    [
    "Track 01": {"Artist": "Chet Baker", "Song": "Alone Together"},
    "Track 02": {"Artist": "BADBADNOTGOOD", "Song": "Confessions (Feat. LeLand Whitty)"},
    "Track 03": {"Artist": "John Buzon Trio", "Song": "iLL Wind"},
    "Track 04": {"Artist": "Peggy Lee", "Song": "Black Coffee"},
    "Track 05": {"Artist": "Melody Gardot", "Song": "Your Heart Is As Black As Night"},
    "Track 06": {"Artist": "Danger Mouse", "Song": "Morning Fog"},
    "Track 07": {"Artist": "Miles Davis", "Song": "Generique"},
    "Track 08": {"Artist": "Vikki Carr", "Song": "The Silences"},
    "Track 09": {"Artist": "Alfred Hitchcock", "Song": "Music To Be Murdered By"},
    "Track 10": {"Artist": "Barry Adamson", "Song": "State Of Contraction"},
    "Track 11": {"Artist": "Skalpel", "Song": "Flying Officer"},
    "Track 12": {"Artist": "Skalpel", "Song": "Together"},
    "Track 13": {"Artist": "Portishead", "Song": "Only You"},
    "Track 14": {"Artist": "Soel", "Song": "Prelude"},
    "Track 15": {"Artist": "Ray Anthony", "Song": "The Shadow Of Your Smile Days Of Wine And Roses"},
    "Track 16": {"Artist": "Twin Danger", "Song": "No One Knows"},
    "Track 17": {"Artist": "Scott Bradlee’s Postmodern Jukebox", "Song": "No Diggity (Feat Ariana Savalas)"},
    "Track 18": {"Artist": "Tom Waits", "Song": "Small Change"},
    "Track 19": {"Artist": "Eddie Higgins & Scott Hamilton", "Song": "My Funny Valentine"}
    ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a pretty good setup but there are a few flaws. You won't be able to actually use this. You have your objects and your arrays mixed up in tract list. You just need to decide what you want to do.

As it currently stands you have an object with an array inside of it. For `Tracklist`

```
Tracklist: {[]}
```

For this to work you would have to have a key for the array removing the outer brackets and making `tracklist:` the key and an array of the track list. This allows you to remove "Track 01, Track 02, etc..." since it is an Array they are already indexed for you. So you can just loop over the track lists.

```
tracklist: [... Array Contents in Here]
```

Another thing to note is that I would advise using `camelCase` for your key names. Spaces are not allowed So you cannot do "Mix Type, Track 01, Track 02" common practice is to use `camelCase` "mixTape or mixtape", track01, track02, tracklist, title, mixDate, trackCount and so on.

Below is one way that you can reformat your current Object to make it more accessible and usable

```js
{
"title": "Notes For The HiFi",
"volume": "One",
"mixDate": "September, 2015",
"duration": "59:09",
"trackCount": 19,
"mixType": "Blend Mix",
"tracklist": [
  {"artist": "Chet Baker", "song": "Alone Together"},
  {"artist": "BADBADNOTGOOD", "song": "Confessions (Feat. LeLand Whitty)"},
    {"artist": "John Buzon Trio", "song": "iLL Wind"},
    {"artist": "Peggy Lee", "song": "Black Coffee"},
    {"artist": "Melody Gardot", "song": "Your Heart Is As Black As Night"},
    {"artist": "Danger Mouse", "song": "Morning Fog"},
    {"artist": "Miles Davis", "song": "Generique"},
    {"artist": "Vikki Carr", "song": "The Silences"},
    {"artist": "Alfred Hitchcock", "song": "Music To Be Murdered By"},
    {"artist": "Barry Adamson", "song": "State Of Contraction"},
    {"artist": "Skalpel", "song": "Flying Officer"},
    {"artist": "Skalpel", "song": "Together"},
    {"artist": "Portishead", "song": "Only You"},
    
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. This makes sense. I was initially scared about losing track number but now being in an array I'm just 0 indexed for track list - thanks again

Comment: @mikevarela No problem if you want the track the # you can add it as another property in the tracklist object, trackNumber: "Track 01" or during you loop you can Just make a string and use the index + 1